# Loop problems Even Count

Tags: python-2.7

I have a beginner question. Loops are extremely hard for me to understand, so it's come to me asking for help.

I am trying to create a function to count the amount of even numbers in a user input list, with a negative at the end to show the end of the list. I know I need to use a while loop, but I am having trouble figuring out how to walk through the indexes of the input list. This is what I have so far, can anyone give me a hand?

```
def find_even_count(numlist):
count = 0
numlist.split()
while numlist > 0:
    if numlist % 2 == 0:
        count += 1
return count        

numlist = raw_input("Please enter a list of numbers, with a negative at the end: ")
print find_even_count(numlist)
```

I used the split to separate out the indexes of the list, but I know I am doing something wrong. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong, or point me to a good step by step explanation of what to do here? 
Thank you guys so much, I know you probably have something more on your skill level to do, but appreciate the help!

Comment: `numbest` is not defined. Please post the code you're using

Comment: Thhat is what I am using, I think my mac tried to autocorrect, the "numbest" in the "print find_even_count" should be "numlist"

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close, just a couple of corrections:

```
def find_even_count(numlist):
    count = 0
    lst = numlist.split()
    for num in lst:
        if int(num) % 2 == 0:
            count += 1
    return count        

numlist = raw_input("Please enter a list of numbers, with a negative at the end: ")
print find_even_count(numlist)
```

I have used a for loop rather than a while loop, stored the outcome of `numlist.split()` to a variable (lst) and then just iterated over this.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems:

1. You `split` `numlist`, but don't assign the resulting list to anything.
2. You then try to operate on `numlist`, which is still the string of all numbers.
3. You never try to convert anything to a number.

Instead, try:

```
def find_even_count(numlist):
    count = 0
    for numstr in numlist.split(): # iterate over the list
        num = int(numstr) # convert each item to an integer
        if num < 0:
            break # stop when we hit a negative
        elif num % 2 == 0:
            count += 1 # increment count for even numbers
    return count # return the total
```

Or, doing the whole thing in one line:

```
def find_even_count(numlist):
    return sum(num % 2 for num in map(int, numlist.split()) if num > 0)
```

*(Note: the one-liner will fail in cases where the user tries to trick you by putting more numbers after the "final" negative number, e.g. with `numlist = "1 2 -1 3 4"`)*

If you must use a `while` loop (which isn't really the best tool for the job), it would look like:

```
def find_even_count(numlist):
    index = count = 0
    numlist = list(map(int, numlist.split()))
    while numlist[index] > 0:
        if numlist[index] % 2 == 0:
            count += 1
        index += 1
    return count
```

Comment: Hold on guys, I am trying to respond.

Comment: I am trying to stay with a while loop, as that is the point of the exercise. You guys are very talented thanks for responding so quick...
I am looking over both of your answers, and I see that I did not ever assign the split to anything.

`def find_even_count(numbest):`

`count = 0`

`nums = int(numlist)`
`nums = nums.split()`
`numlist = raw_input("Please enter a list of numbers, with a negative at the end: ")`
`print find_even_count(numbest)`
I keep getting "invalid literal for int() with base 10" back... I am trying to convert the split numlist to an integer.
edit: I can't get it to switch

Comment: @Loomiss you have to apply the `int` to each item after the `split`; you can't turn e.g. `"1 2 -3"` into an `int` directly. I have added an example `while`-based implementation.